# Update branch not current with master

Tags: git

I have a problem and it is that I have a very old branch that I want to upgrade but will 239 commits behind, would have any way to upgrade the branch of a fast and simple way, currently the branch has not been touched everything there is in the branch is master what I is  bring me my rapa master without conflicts to update it with all the commits.

A greeting and thank you.

Comment: git pull and handle the merge conflicts. The other option is to clone the repo all over again.

Comment: Cloning the repo all over again and loosing history is never a solution, and there is a lot of different options.

Comment: I think you would have to do the dirty work of merging the code manually

Answer (score 0):

It's depends to a lot of things, depending of how many changes / conflicts there is, how many commits are in the old branch, if you want to get all commits or if some of them can be discarded…

From your `oldbranch`, You can try `git rebase master`. If you have to solve several times the same conflicts, you can abort the rebase (`git rebase --abort`) and configure git to «Reuse Recorded Resolution» with  `git config --global rerere.enabled true`.

If you want to discard some commits, you can do `git rebase master --interactive` and remove the line corresponding to commits you don't want.

Another alternative is to go on master branch and use `git cherry-pick [list of commit hash from the old branch you want]`.

There is no magic command, but using a difftool like `vimdiff` or `meld` will help you a lot for resolving conflicts with `git mergetool`.